# how to delete get checked checkbox in yii2

Tags: yii2

I  want to delete data from multiple checkbox selected I fetch data from ajax request through but I don't know next process.

This is ajax form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#MyButton").click(function ()
                {
                    var id = $('#grid').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
                    alert(id);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url:'index.php?r=usermaster/multipledelete',
                        data: {id: id},
                        success: function () {
                            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
</script>
```

What exactly I want to delete this multiple data I got id through the ajax form

```
public function actionMultipledelete($id)
{    
    if (\Yii::$app->request->post()) {
        $keys = \Yii::$app->request->post('id'); // id is array
    }
    if (!empty($keys)) {
        $this->findModel($keys)->delete();
    }
 }
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the action code, this may help you:

```php
public function actionMultipledelete($id)
{
    if (\Yii::$app->request->post()) {
        $keys = \Yii::$app->request->post('id'); // id is array
    }
    if (!empty($keys)) {
        foreach($keys as $id) { 
            $this->findModel($id)->delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you must use loop for it as `$keys` will be array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126287/discussion-between-nitin-and-sms).

Comment: but there is problem delete only one row not deleting selected row by checkbox